# Creating a computational table to show the number of available genes between all possible pairs of combinations in eight gene lists

Tags: r, rstudio

I am looking to create a table (on RStudio) that will show the overlap between 8 different gene lists wherever possible. I have saved the 8 lists as .txt files all in one folder and set that particular folder as my working directory. Any idea of code that will work for this?

[image: Output table with NA values]

If anyone knows what I can alter to make the current code work or suggest an alternative way I would be very happy to hear any suggestions!

```
data.file1 <- "GSE108363_BCGdown_V.txt"
data.file2 <- "GSE108363_BCGdown_D.txt"
data.file3 <- "GSE108363_BCGup_V.txt"
data.file4 <- "GSE108363_BCGup_D.txt"
data.file5 <- "GSE108363_MTBdown_V.txt"
data.file6 <- "GSE108363_MTBdown_D.txt"
data.file7 <- "GSE108363_MTBup_V.txt"
data.file8 <- "GSE108363_MTBup_D.txt"

genevect1 <- scan(data.file1, what=character(), sep="\n")
genevect2 <- scan(data.file2, what=character(), sep="\n")
genevect3 <- scan(data.file3, what=character(), sep="\n")
genevect4 <- scan(data.file4, what=character(), sep="\n")
genevect5 <- scan(data.file5, what=character(), sep="\n")
genevect6 <- scan(data.file6, what=character(), sep="\n")
genevect7 <- scan(data.file7, what=character(), sep="\n")
genevect8 <- scan(data.file8, what=character(), sep="\n")


filelist <- list(data.file1, data.file2, data.file3, data.file4, data.file5, data.file6, data.file7, data.file8)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "Lapply" is basically making a "for loop".
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
all_gene_vectors <- lapply(filelist, scan, what=character(), sep="\n")

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Then make the intersection of *all* genesets
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
final_inter <- all_gene_vectors[[1]]
for (next_genevect in all_gene_vectors[2:length(all_gene_vectors)]) {
  final_inter <- intersect(final_inter, next_genevect)
}
show(final_inter)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Or compute all pairwise intersections (untested)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pairwise_inters <- list()
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Iterate over all possible pairs i,j (i ≠ j)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
N <- length(all_gene_vectors)
for (i in 1:(N-1)) {
  ith_inters <- list()
  for (j in (i+1):N) {
    ith_inters[[ names(all_gene_vectors)[j ]]] <- intersect(all_gene_vectors[[i]], all_gene_vectors[[j]])
  }
  pairwise_inters[[ names(all_gene_vectors)[i] ]] <- ith_inters
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Generate table in wide format:
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
#Concatenate gene names of all tables to a separate file
#Extract unique values in this file
#Perform outer join between the separate file and each table

all_names <- c(data.list)
for (tp in timepoints){
  all_names <- append(all_names, tables[[tp]]$genes)
}
all_names <- unique(all_names)

wide_table <- matrix(nrow=length(all_names), ncol=(1+length(timepoints)))
wide_table <- as.data.frame(wide_table)
colnames(wide_table) <- append("genes", timepoints)

for (tp in timepoints){
  tmp <- tables[[tp]]
  tmp$tp <- 1
  tmp <- merge(wide_table, tmp, by="genes", all=T)
  wide_table$tp <- tmp$tp
}


set.seed(11)
BCG_validation_Up <- sample(letters[1:429], 20)
BCG_discovery_Up <- sample(letters[1:250], 20)
MTB_validation_Up <- sample(letters[1:286], 20)
MTB_discovery_Up <- sample(letters[1:128], 20)
BCG_validation_Down <- sample(letters[1:267], 20)
BCG_discovery_Down  <- sample(letters[1:350], 20)
MTB_validation_Down <- sample(letters[1:244], 20)
MTB_discovery_Down <- sample(letters[1:86], 20)

cross_table <- matrix(, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
rownames(cross_table) <- c("BCG_validation_Up", "BCG_discovery_Up", "MTB_validation_Up", "MTB_discovery_Up")
colnames(cross_table) <- c("BCG_validation_Down", "BCG_discovery_Down", "MTB_validation_Up", "MTB_discovery_Up")

for (i in 1:4){
  for(j in 1:4){
    cross_table[i,j] <- length(intersect(get(paste0("",i,"_Up")),(get(paste0("",j,"_Down")))))
  }
} 

cross_table
```

Comment: Please show how the end table should look like, and give a small example to test with.

Comment: It looks like you already have code. Can you describe why what you have is not acceptable?

Comment: @winni2k Yes but I get the following error code when I attempt to execute it: Error in ith_inters[[names(all_gene_vectors)[j]]] <- intersect(all_gene_vectors[[i]],  : 
  attempt to select less than one element in OneIndex

Comment: @b.nota I have inserted a screenshot of the table I would like to be filled in, please find it above

Comment: That's a confusion matrix of 4 x 4, but you have 8 lists. Do you want a 8 x 8 confusion matrix or do you combine some of the lists?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code! That just makes the question heavier to load, useless for people using screen readers and, most importantly, makes the code you show useless to us. We need to be able to copy your code and run it locally to test any solutions we come up with. Please [edit] your question and include the code here directly. Use the [formatting tools](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: @b.nota What i meant was a 4x4 table with 4 of them referring to upregulated genes and the other 4 for down regulated genes

Comment: @terdon Thanks for letting me know, I didn't know that it was so inconvenient for you and others. Please find my question edited.

Comment: @user3762, that was absolutely not clear from the question!

Comment: @b.nota Apologies, I hope it is all clear now

Comment: @b.nota Thanks for your suggested answer. I will check to see it works fine. Just wanted to ask why you have used (,20) in particular in all of the brackets? And why 11 in set.seed?

Comment: I made a workable example by generating lists of random letters (20 letters each). The set.seed command is to get the same letters each time. I made this workable example because you did not give a workable example.

Comment: Hi @user3762, I am sensing a bit of confusion and frustration in the comments to your question. I think some of that could be avoided if you edited your post to be about a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

To make a confusion matrix of 4 lists against 4 other lists, you need to get the length of all intersecting genes for each pair. Here an example with letters instead of gene names.

```
set.seed(11)
list1_up <- sample(letters[1:26], 20)
list1_down <- sample(letters[1:26], 20)
list2_up <- sample(letters[1:26], 20)
list2_down <- sample(letters[1:26], 20)
list3_up <- sample(letters[1:26], 20)
list3_down <- sample(letters[1:26], 20)
list4_up <- sample(letters[1:26], 20)
list4_down <- sample(letters[1:26], 20)

cross_table <- matrix(, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
rownames(cross_table) <- c("list1_up", "list2_up", "list3_up", "list4_up")
colnames(cross_table) <- c("list1_down", "list2_down", "list3_down", "list4_down")

for (i in 1:4){
  for(j in 1:4){
    cross_table[i,j] <- length(intersect(get(paste0("list",i,"_up")),(get(paste0("list",j,"_down")))))
    }
} 

cross_table
         list1_down list2_down list3_down list4_down
list1_up         15         14         15         15
list2_up         18         15         15         15
list3_up         17         15         14         16
list4_up         17         15         15         16
```

Comment: Please could you look at my attempt at altering this code to suit my data and see where I have gone wrong? I have added the code to my question above

Comment: No, I will not look at your attempt. Here is my suggestion, do with it what you want.

Comment: @user3762 It would be better if you describe what has gone wrong and how the solution here fails you. Also show your attempts to fix or adapt this solution into one that works for you. Good luck!

Comment: @benn nice manners